# How to add OG meta to Shopify descriptions?

Tags: automation, seo, shopify, og-meta

How can I automatically add the OG meta description from Twitter to the meta description in Shopify?

`<meta property="og:description" content="here is the meta description i want to automatically add to the shopify description for every product.">`

Answer (score 0):

```
{%- if template_base == 'product' -%}
<meta property="og:description" content="here is the meta description i want to automatically add to the shopify description for every product.">
{%- endif -%}
```

you can add this code to theme.liquid